# how to define in rails model json method to generate json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model

I am having this rather long json output in my controller, I wish to move it into the model as it seems to be a good practice. First off, the controller method:

```
def dashboard
  @line_items = LineItem.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @line_items.as_json(include: {project: {include: {spec: {methods: [:dashboard_due_at]} },methods:[:company_name, :contacts_names, :owner_names] }}, methods:[:dashboard_created_at, :dashboard_length])}
  end
end
```

How can I move everything starting from as_json into the LineItem model so that I can just do

```
format.json { render  json: @line_items.dashboard_json }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your LineItem model

```
def dashboard_json
  as_json(include: {project: {include: {spec: {methods: [:dashboard_due_at]} },
    methods:[:company_name, :contacts_names, :owner_names] }},
    methods:[:dashboard_created_at, :dashboard_length])
end
```